# Prove that, if $0<y<1$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural numbers $n$ such that $y^{n} < \epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Prove that, if $0<y<1$, then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural numbers $n$ such that $y^{n} < \epsilon$.

I've tried everything. The case $\epsilon > 1$ is relatively easy to do but I'm stuck on $0 < \epsilon < 1$. I'm thinking of doing a proof by contradiction but I have no idea as to how I can formulate the hypothesis to be disproven. I'm not allowed to use limits.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [infima](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Infimum.html)? ​ ​

Comment: Is epsilon given at the beginning of the problem or are we trying to prove its existence? I think there is something wrong with your question.

Comment: “_Prove that, if $0<y<1$, then, for all natural numbers $n$, there exist an $\epsilon$ such that $y^{n} < \epsilon$._” This doesn’t look right to me, in particular because you already chose $\epsilon$. Do you maybe want to show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exstists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $y^n < \varepsilon$?

Comment: I think the statement should say that for all $y$ and $\epsilon$ there exists $n$. Otherwise it's easy, just pick $\epsilon = 2$.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Apologies. The statement is actually "For every $\epsilon$>0, there exists a natural number n". I'm going to modify it right away. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is this basically asking for a proof that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y^n=0$ for $0<y<1$?

Answer (score 1):

I will prove the correct statement of this problem.

The trick is to write $y = \frac{1}{1 + d}$ with $d > 0$ then use Newton binomial formula. 
\begin{align}
0 < y^n = \frac{1}{(1 + d)^n} = \frac{1}{1 + nd + \cdots + d^n} < \frac{1}{nd}.
\end{align}
So given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N = \left\lceil\frac{1}{d\epsilon}\right\rceil$, thus for all $n > N$, we can have $0 < y^n < \epsilon$.